# Joomla's jdoc:include style

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-module

i am new in Joomla. 
i found this code in my Template:

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="search" style="xhtml">
```

but i do not understand , whats this `style="xhtml"` refer ?
in my other joomla template , i see below code:

```
<jdoc:include type="modules" name="footer" style="e4jstyle">
```

so, whats this style means ? i change this style name, but didn't see any change.

Please, can anyone explain this code?

Answer (score 4):

This is known as **module chrome** and it's an easy way to wrap extra html around the module output so you can style the front-end result. There are a number of different options, here's one reference to get you started: http://docs.joomla.org/Standard_Module_Chromes

It's not on the list above, but one I like to use for Joomla 3 is `style="html5"`

**EDIT**
This will get you started if you want to roll your own module styles: http://docs.joomla.org/Applying_custom_module_chrome

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks David for reference. but i didn't see style="e4jstyle"   

can we make custom style="anything"? or all i need to call every time this reference ??
thanks ..

Comment: @hassan, some sytles are built-in to your Joomla installation, and then you can design your own. style="e4jstyle" will be a custom style defined in your Joomla template. See my edit above for details of how to do this.